# Libreoffice Headless PPTx File convert to PDF producing background color to the text in the output

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, headless, libreoffice-writer, docx-to-pdf-conversion

I am Using Libreoffice V7.3.7.2 and

headless command to convert pptx file using --convert-to pdf command in the Ubuntu system,

the converted PDF is getting added with the background color to the heading text.

As well as all my gdrive files text is striking off while conversion.

Please find the input file image as Original Document and have a look over the converted document

[Original Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo8q9.png)

[Converted Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuHf.png)

Here is my input command
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /mydir/ /localpath/file.pptx

The converted PDF is not as same as the provided input PPTX file.

May I know the reason why and the corresponding solution related to the same?

or

May I know the correct filter options to convert pptx file to pdf without missing the text formatting atleast?

Comment: @KJ Thank you for your response, there is no issue in scale wise. The only issue here is style wise. I had taken the screenshots to update here. hence you might have noticed that change. Another strange behavior of styling we are facing due to remote server in AWS ec2 instance. in the local device, the text is appearing as same. Need to figure out for styles filters of libreoffice as you mentioned. Thank you once again.